# Automatically shrink stretched images back to their original dimensions

Tags: image-processing, automation

We all sometimes find images on the web that are carelessly stretched to larger dimensions than original, which results in nothing but a reduction of the detail / dimensions ratio.

See **Original** vs **Stretched** below:

---

Source: Kaley Cuoco (Model), Esquire (Latin America)

## Original

[image: original]

## Stretched

[image: stretched]

---

Questions:

1. Given only **Stretched**, is there a way to automatically find the best dimensions to shrink *Stretched* down to which maximizes the `detail / dimensions` ratio?
2. Is there a generic way to define `detail` for all images (photos, line-art, text, etc.)?
3. Is 'stretched' the correct term or is there a more technically correct applicable?

Comment: Is this question about *Mathematica* or image processing in general?

Comment: @YvesKlett it is about a working examplery implementation in *Mathematica* but general answers with hints might also be useful.

Comment: There's a lot to read [here](http://fotoforensics.com/tutorial.php), particularly about Error level Analysis, but I'm not convinced that simple resizing operations are going to show up, although I know little about it...

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer to your general questions is "no" there is no way that is going to allow you to figure out the original size of an image given only the upsampled (or resized) image in all cases. If you know the correct size to aim for, the mechanics in Mathematica would be simple:

```
 ImageResize[image , desiredSize]
```

So, how might you go about this? One thing is to note that if the image has been upsampled, then it has no more information in it than a smaller version. So you might try something like this:

(1) resize to a smaller version
(2) resize back from the smaller version to the larger size
(3) compare your new (doubly resized image) to the original
(4) if there is not much difference, then you might as well keep the smaller one

Then do this for several candidate sizes until you find the best one. Of course, step (3) requires a measure of closeness of images. For this you might try `ImageDistance`.

Comment: +1 Good advice. However, I fear the result of your workflow might depend more on your choice of resampling method than on internal characteristics of the image.

Comment: True... but there are only about 23 methods under the `Resampling` help. So at least it's not infinite!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't matter *how* many methods are available: since they all lead to arbitrary results, it won't do any good to try them all. The problem stems from the inherent (potential) change of information content in the originally resized image compared to the (unknown) original image. All your procedure does is evaluate some of the statistical properties of these resampling procedures as applied to one particular input image.